# Aligning at differents levels

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line, split

I would like to know which could be the simplest way to obtain  something like[image]
Where each sequence of letters represent a long expression. To be more precise I want that the sequence of b's to start in the same position that the sequence of a's, the sequence of c's start aligned with the second min and the sequence of d's start a little further to the right than  sequence of c's.
I have obtained the output of the picture by using several `\hspace{}` but I would like to avoid this.

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{l l}
    \begin{split}
        L=\min \bigg\lbrace \min \left\lbrace  \right.  & aaaaaaaaaaaaa,  \\
        &bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \left. \right\rbrace 
    \end{split}\\
    \hspace{2,1cm}cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc \\
    \hspace{2,3cm}dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd\bigg\rbrace
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some nested `aligned` environments, with an anchor at the `[t]`op:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  L = \min \Bigl\{\begin{aligned}[t]
    & \min \bigl\{\begin{aligned}[t]
        & aaaaaaaaaaaaa, \\
        & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \bigr\}
      \end{aligned} \\
    & cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc \\
    & \quad dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd \Bigr\}
  \end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

Since `aligned` assumes a `R&L` construction, with the first set of content `R`ight-aligned, followed by `&` and the second set of content `L`eft-aligned, we insert a `&` without any `R`ight-aligned content, making everything `L`eft-aligned by default.

The two nested `aligned` environments construct the output using the following layout:

- outer `aligned` is denoted in RED, and
- inner `aligned` is denoted in GREEN.

[image]